# Find areas of values with the same value in a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array like:

```
my_array = [[3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
            [3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]
```

I would like to check the starts and ends of a portion of the array with the same values (different from 0). So in the example above I would like to get something like:

```
result = [(0,0,1,1), (2,3,4,5)]
```

Where each tuple on the list is (i_start, j_start, i_end, j_end)

Is there any function that achieves something similar?

Comment: The likely answer is "no". And I think your example is wrong: your second block seems to correspond to a 2x2 rectangle, but your array contains a 3x2 rectangle. What if the contiguous area is not rectangle-shaped? The problem is highly ill-defined.

Comment: `[(i_start, i_end), (j_start, j_end)]` is more intuitive. Also, are the areas rectangular? You'll have to write your own code to do this.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is [looking for bounding boxes of objects in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689173/shape-recognition-with-numpy-scipy-perhaps-watershed). Consider your array to be an image, 0 is the background, 1 and 3 are the objects inside.